# My device is not showing on Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

For the past week or so my Android device which is connected via USB is not listed in Android Studio so I am unable to get the logcat messages nor can I terminate the app.

From Android Studio it detects that my device is plugged in but in the Android tab it does not list the app so I am unable to click it and then click terminate.

Anyone know how I fix this?

Comment: first check from terminal by using command "adb devices"

Comment: in terminal              Microsoft Windows [Version 6.1.7600]
Copyright (c) 2009 Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Ramesh\AndroidStudioProjects\Mynew>M E#^A

ony this text is how

Comment: open command prompt in windows and write adb devices what your result??

Answer (score 0):

Yes, here is the exact solution of your problem,

1. First of all check that the debugging mode is on into your device.
2. check the android api level of your device
3. Then go to android studio
4. open the  `GrandleScript->build.gradle`
   [Figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kawto.png)
   your build.gradle would be something like that
5. Then change the sdk version according to your attached device
6. Change buildtoolbar according to yours
7. change Target sdk
8. And finally in dependencies change the value of com.android.support:appcompat-v7: to your device level
9. keep in mind the value of above com.android... should be of 3 digits separated by dots(.) like mine of 19.1.0+
   Hope so its is enough for Android studio subject error and also for Eclipse subject error.

Comment: Please format your answer. You can add nicely looking lists.

Comment: Please do not spam the same answer to multiple questions.  Take more time for each answer you write instead of creating a catch-all.  Alternatively, once you reach 50 reputation, you should instead close the questions as duplicates.  Your answers are currently being [discussed on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/309915/what-to-do-when-a-user-has-posted-the-same-answer-two-times).